# How to scroll by line/pixel in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have 5 short articles in a div box with scrollbar.

When i scroll in div it  should goes automatically another article. Kind of css scroll snap points

Like down 50 px. How to do this with CSS or another thing. Thanks in advance.

[First article](https://tosunkaya.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/scroll1.jpg)

[Second article](https://tosunkaya.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/scroll2.jpg)

THIS IS ANOTHER EX: https:// dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/1449529764snappoints-03.gif

Another ex: http:// codepen.io/sdras/pen/43c9d13b23bc34a85bb3a5e2ea985958

http:// www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_scrollto

https:// blog.hospodarets.com/demos/scroll-snap-full-screen/#screen1

Comment: One of the examples you posted is on codepen already? Did you check how it is done there?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out: https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points/

Will take a few more lines than you might think, also browser compatibility isn't at it's best.

Comment: same code isnt working on my website and jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/5330gk8t/)